# Firefox: How to open tabs from the history in the background?

Tags: firefox

If I search for an page visited I sometimes need to check several similar history entries. Default of Firefox is, that every time I right-click and select open in new tab, the new tab opens and the history-window disapears.
For bookmarks I found out, that you can tweak in about:config the
`browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInBackground`
and
`browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs`
to true, so that firefox opens bookmarks in a new tab and in the background.

I thought I found the same for my history problem with
`browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground`
However, now it opens any "diverted" new tab in a background tab, but I only want it for new tabs out of the history window and not e.g. when clicking on a link in a pdf. Then I want the clicked link to pop up directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have "`browser.search.context.loadinbackground`" set to `true` on my Firefox (version 86.0b7).
In the Library->History menu, as well as the History sidebar, I can Middle-Click to have the URL open in the background.

For completeness, I also have these set to "`true`":

```
browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInBackground
browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground
browser.tabs.loadInBackground
browser.search.openintab
browser.urlbar.openintab
browser.tabs.opentabfor.middleclick
browser.urlbar.openintab
middlemouse.openNewWindow
```

Hope that helps you.
Regards,
Andi

Comment: you are my todays hero. setting `browser.search.context.loadinbackground` to `true` does indeed work as intended. (open tabs via history in the background, but tabs from external programms in the front)!

Comment: Glad to be of service :-)

Answer (score 0):

control + shift + left mouse click opens in background tab for me